# Combine two responses both different typescript types in one list

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to combine two different responses into one, both share a common key/value pair, distance. I need to combine these two json objects into one. sorted on distance.
I've tried doing it is way:

```
const test: [Group, Profile] = [].concat(profiles, groups)

export type Profile = {
  userId: string
  imageId: string
  firstname: string
  middleName: string
  lastname: string
  distance: number
}

export type Group= {
  groupId: string
  name: string
  distance: number
}
```

Is this possible? im getting an error:

> Argument of type 'Profile[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'ConcatArray'.

Comment: Remove the type annotation. It is simultaneously incorrect (it should be `(Group | Profile)[]`) and unnecessary as the inferred type is just what you want. Also, the empty array is pointless - just write `const test = groups.concat(profiles);` or `const test = [...groups, ...profiles];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `concat` is a little awkward because it assumes the arguments have the same type, but you can do it elegantly by spreading the arrays: `[...profiles, ...groups]`.

Note that `[Group, Profile]` is not the right type for the result, as this is an array of length 2 containing a `Group` and a `Profile`. Instead, you can use an array of the union of `Group` and `Profile`, like this:

```
type ProfileOrGroup = Profile | Group

const test: ProfileOrGroup[] = [...profiles, ...groups]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADgTg9gMwJagM4C4IAV7NAbQF0IBeCIgKFEgHN4BXKDCAcQaiNPMIorAE8oIbLhQgA8jDZxGXHIjEQAPq3a8AxnAB2qSGBC7M8vBKntOZfADobsBWgA0EG1boymPCiAAeUODD1BYWNFMgBvCggIelQQGABJABNMXRgkLRpIiCQAWwBDGhAklLA0jKzkGF0tPJyQErLMqJykRMTQADla%20ohU9KaIYDzq7ob%20rMSkXTytdR6tehyAIziKAF9eHz8AiAEhVXdwrLdGYt7S8aiaurHyqMnp2fnFlZh1iiA)